# Kotlin file to apk android flow?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

What is execution flow of Kotlin file to apk in android. Using Java file like this
.Java file -> .class file -> classes.dex -> .apk file. Refer [this](https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid/wiki/How-Android-Apps-are-Built-and-Run)

for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin can be compiled to java classfile format, so it's: .kt file -> .class file -> classes.dex -> .apk file.

It differs from the Java to APK tool chain only in the first step, I wrote a simple explaination in the format of your given link:

### Kotlin compilation

Your code is written in kotlin. But is that kotlin code compiled and run the same way as, say, a web application?

The compilation process for Android apps written in kotlin is very different from other Java applications. But it begins in the same way: your kotlin source code files are compiled into .class files using the `kotlinc` command (assuming you have installed kotlin and your source file is named `activity.kt`):

```
kotlinc activity.kt
```

or use [other](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) [build](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html) [tool](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-ant.html) to compile.

This converts kotlin code like this:

```
class MainActivity(): XXX {
    init {
        currentPosition = 0
    }
}
```

into Java byte-codes representing Java assembly that looks something like this:

```
public com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.MainActivity();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #5; //Method android/app/Activity."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   iconst_0
   6:   putfield    #3; //Field currentPosition:I
   9:   return
```

Comment: Can you give me link for more details of execution ??

Comment: It means it uses java compiler to convert .kt -> .class file right ??

Comment: Kotlin is a new language. It uses it own compiler to compile kotlin sources into various targets, one of which is Java Bytecode.

Comment: Ok. Is there other possibilities than Java Bytecode as a compilation target in order to build an app ? Also, you say : "The compilation process for Android apps written in kotlin is very different from other Java applications. But it begins in the same way: your kotlin source code files are compiled into .class files", but what differs more than the compilation into `.class` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
kotlinc example.kt -include-runtime -d example.apk
```